# React InstantSearch (with Typesense): facets not working with multiple collections

Tags: reactjs, react-instantsearch, typesense

I am using [React InstantSearch](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/react/) with the [Typesense adapater](https://github.com/typesense/typesense-instantsearch-adapter).

Our search data has two collections - emails and attachments.

- Both collections have a facet for sender's email (`from_email`)
- Attachments also have a facet for file extension (`ext`)

If I configure my search for one of the collections only everything works as expected but for some reason I cannot get file type refinement list to work if I have both collections in use.

If I have both collections in use no matter what I select from file type refinement list it does not affect search results. I am clearly not using the search correctly but cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Simplified version of my code:

```js
import {
  useMemo,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import {
  Configure,
  Index,
  InstantSearch,
} from 'react-instantsearch';
import TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter from 'typesense-instantsearch-adapter';

function EmailSearch() {

  const searchClient = useMemo(() => {
    if (userConfig) {
      const typesenseInstantsearchAdapter = new TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter({
        server: {
          apiKey: userConfig.search.apiKey,
          nodes: [...],
        },
        collectionSpecificSearchParameters: {
          collection_emails: {
            query_by: 'subject,from_name,from_email,body',
          },
          collection_attachments: {
            query_by: 'filename,content,ext',
          },
        },
      });

      return typesenseInstantsearchAdapter.searchClient;
    }
    return null;
  }, [userConfig]);

  return (
    <InstantSearch
      searchClient={searchClient}
      indexName="collection_emails"
      future={{
        preserveSharedStateOnUnmount: true,
      }}
    >
      <Configure hitsPerPage={5} />

      <CustomSearchBox /> { /* Custom search box component */ }
      <FromRefinementList attribute="from_email" /> { /* both collections have "from_email" */ }
      <Index indexName="collection_attachments">
        <FileTypeRefinementList attribute="ext" /> { /* only attachments have "ext" */ }
      </Index>

      <Index indexName="collection_emails">
        <EmailHits />
      </Index>
      <Index indexName="collection_attachments">
        <AttachmentHits />
      </Index>

    </InstantSearch>
  );
}
```

When I select one email address from `FromRefinementList` and one file type from `FileTypeRefinementList` this is what is sent to the search engine:

```
"searches": [
  {
    "query_by": "subject,from_name,from_email,body",
    "collection": "collection_emails",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "filter_by": "from_email:=[`john@example.com`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 5
  },
  {
    "query_by": "subject,from_name,from_email,body",
    "collection": "collection_emails",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "query_by": "filename,content,ext",
    "collection": "collection_attachments",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "ext,from_email",
    "filter_by": "ext:=[`pdf`] && from_email:=[`john@example.com`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 5
  },
  {
    "query_by": "filename,content,ext",
    "collection": "collection_attachments",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "ext",
    "filter_by": "from_email:=[`john@example.com`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "query_by": "filename,content,ext",
    "collection": "collection_attachments",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "filter_by": "ext:=[`pdf`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "query_by": "subject,from_name,from_email,body",
    "collection": "collection_emails",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "filter_by": "from_email:=[`john@example.com`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 5
  },
  {
    "query_by": "subject,from_name,from_email,body",
    "collection": "collection_emails",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1
  },
  {
    "query_by": "filename,content,ext",
    "collection": "collection_attachments",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "filter_by": "from_email:=[`john@example.com`]",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 5
  },
  {
    "query_by": "filename,content,ext",
    "collection": "collection_attachments",
    "q": "*",
    "facet_by": "from_email",
    "max_facet_values": 10,
    "page": 1
  }
]
```

Comment: I've had a similar problem using instant-search-js and I ended up dropping the lib as a whole. It's good to prototype, but horrible to operate efficiently and to maintain for complex use-cases. The typesense-js library is perfect for querying typesense and provides most of the functionalities you need. 
My experience was that the result code was 1000x shorter, simpler and I was able to customize much more easily the UI.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @yco. Did you create a custom context provider and hooks, too? That's the main thing I use React InstantSearch for. All UI components are already custom components.

Comment: Yes, and they are quite easy to reproduce. with a react context and react-query for caching, that is not too much work to have the basics. Facetting (aka, Refinement) needs a little more implementation since you have to perform multi-search (1 for the search query with the filtered faceted value, 1 for the the facet values)